# Python одиночная выборочная замена цифр

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Python Задача такова:** заменить цифру в даном цисле так, чтобы оно **нацело** делилось на 3. Цифру **заменять обязательно**. Даже если и до этого делилось на 3. Менять можно **только одну цифру**. После найти **наибольшее возможное число** и вывести его.

**Пример:** Input: 1, out:3. ----- Input: 21, out: 24. ----- Input 454, out: 456.

Вывод должен быть **натуральным числом**. Мучился с кодом. Ничего поделать не могу. Даже не дописал до конца.

```
x_conserv = list(input())
x = x_conserv
predictions = []

for index in range(len(x)): 
    for num in range(0, 10): 
        x[index] = num
        predictions.append(x)


print(x_conserv, x)
print(predictions)
```

Абсолютно не понимаю почему вывод -

```
[9, 9] [9, 9]
[[9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9], [9, 9]]
```

Из своих экспериментов я понял только то, что "=" работает в две стороны. Но это противоречит моим прежним знаниям. Да и потом написал программу, которая опровергла это. Короче запутался я. Спасити пожалуйста).
**Благодаю.**

Comment: Примеры в задании не соответствуют условиям. Наибольшие числа будут 81 и 954.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как работает ваш код:

Вы вводите `x_conserv`, потом в цикле перебираете кол-во элементов, зачем-то повторяете все это 10 раз, и  выводите `x_conserv, x` и `predictions`, по сути 3 списка которые продублировались очень много раз без причины, на самом деле вам хватило бы вот такого кода:

```
x_conserv = [1, 20, 454]
predictions = []

for index in x_conserv :
    while int(index) % 3 != 0:
        index += 1
    predictions.append(index)


print(x_conserv)
print(predictions)
```

Вот ввод и вывод:

```
[1, 21, 454]
[3, 21, 456]
```

Если Вам нужно именно вводить числа с клавиатуры, используйте вот этот вариант

```
x = input().split()
x_conserv = list(map(int, x))
predictions = []

for index in x_conserv :
    while int(index) % 3 != 0:
        index += 1
    predictions.append(index)


print(x_conserv)
print(predictions)
```